# python unittest verify button clicked

Tags: python, unit-testing, button, mocking, pyqt5

I can not make this button clicked verification work, what is wrong with my test?
module minimalExample.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class App(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print('button clicked')
```

module test_minimalExample.py

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch as patch

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtTest import QTest

import minimalExample

class TestApp(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.ctx = QApplication([])

    def test_on_click(self):
        with patch.object(minimalExample.App, 'on_click') as mock:
            app = minimalExample.App()
            QTest.mouseClick(app.button, Qt.LeftButton)
            self.assertTrue(mock.assert_called())
```

I can see in the output that my button gets clicked but I also get:
AssertionError: Expected 'on_click' to have been called.

Answer (score 0):

by adjusting the test_on_click method a bit it works now for my minimalExample:

```
def test_on_click(self):
    with mock.patch('minimalExample.App.on_click') as clickCheck:
        app = minimalExample.App()
        QTest.mouseClick(app.button, Qt.LeftButton)
        self.assertTrue(clickCheck.called)
```